# How to get activated routes childs while in parent routing -angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How can I get my current route's children names?

Below, I need all to know `compo2` children while navigating through it.

```
{ path: 'compo1', component: Component1 },
{ path: 'compo2', loadChildren: 'app/compo.module#Compomodule' },
{ path: '', component: Component1 },
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more what you try to accomplish?. What does "while navigate through it" mean? Where and when do you want access to child routes?

Comment: When i navigate to Compomodule i want to get all routes of Compomodule

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can get it this way:

```
constructor(route:ActivatedRoute) {
  route.children...
}
```